# Is it possible to make an Action "unclickable"?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the ActionBarSherlock library for my application for API level 10. I was wondering if it is possible to have an Action icon that does not respond when it has been clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mainTopBluetoothState"
        android:icon="@drawable/bt_not_connected"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/mainTopAppState"
        android:title="App State"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

The `android:clickable="false"` does not produce an error, but the Action still reacts when pressed while the application is running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `android:enabled` [or `setEnabled()` at runtime on the `MenuItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
mymenu.getItem(0//item number).setEnabled(false);
```

and when you want to `setClickable` just write this...

```
mymenu.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem myItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myId);
        myItem.setEnabled(false);

    return true;  
}
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) recommends it to do it like this.

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. **You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items** or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.